# Why does Akka Actor have only one onReceive() method that able to take messsage

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

Just thinking now. Why does Akka Actor Model have only one `onReceive()` method.

{*I have not used actors in production yet, so excuse me in advance if I misunderstand something. Just thinking about a model in general.*}

Why not have arbitrary methods whatever we need to put to our Actor?

Like why not say that whatever public method we have in our actor they will over `mail-box`, pushing that calls to `that function call queue`?

like this:

```
class MyActor extends ... {
 public void doSomething1(message:String) {...}
 public void doSomtething2(message:MyMessage) {}
}
```

My point is that it might be better to have many methods that represent user calls rather than go over all `instanceof(this)`, `instanceof(that)`

Having methods, but not onReceive one with many cases in there makes code more readable (for me) and provides better code-navigation abilities, making use of IDE help.

**UPDATE:**

Just read about `TypedActors`.

I wonder why do people usually prefer to use untyped actor over typed ones (I've read some chapters in Akka books, seems Untyped ones are default way to go)?

Typed ones seems (to me [at least for that moment]) make code more readable - less 'instanceof' / 'case' - involved. More object-oriented like. More typed like `Java` & `scala` languages are - typed(safe) ones.

Even if use `pattern-matching` in `scala` that does not look so clear as list of methods. As I said - easier to **navigate** in IDE, just clicking on the method so it brings you to exact place.. rather then going over `case: this`.. `case: that`

I'm tempting to say that `case` / `instanceof` - way reminds me that old.. stuff from [WinApi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

Comment: Have you seen [typed actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed-actors.html)?

Comment: Please refer to the classical paper by Waldo et al for a discussion why method call syntax (and hence TypedActors) is a bad idea for distributed systems: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.7628

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a part of Akka team so i can only guess here. But here's my understanding why i would object to the approach you've described.

1. When message is not implemented in the receive function, it does nothing. Most importantly, it doesn't break my system!
2. I can compose behaviors - say, I want uninitialized behavior that is composed of `initializationHandler orElse lifecycleHandler orElse unknownMessageHandler` and easily switch to `businnessProcessHandler orElse lifecycleHandler orElse unknownMessageHandler`, which in your case will lead either to code duplication, and/or storing local state
3. I can parameterize my behavior! You can safely have the code like `def receive = businessProcessHandler(timeout = 5 millis)`, and my partial function will have the timeout available without actually storing it in the actor object.

Comment: Makes sense I guess. Also, I found some answers here:
http://letitcrash.com/post/19074284309/when-to-use-typedactors

In short, It seems it is more convenient to communicate between actor to actor (that often happens in actor's world) communication without knowing an interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The Java onReceive() method for untyped actors is modeled after the original Scala receive() method - since Scala has pattern-matching, there is no need to do instanceof there, you just decompose based on patterns. It's unfortunate that Java doesn't have pattern matching, because decomposition actually offers a better level of abstraction than object-oriented method calls in many cases. Being an event-driven framework, Akka's untyped actors can respond to any complex message type via pattern matching-based decomposition, for example

```
def receive = {
  case head :: tail => println("Not empty list")
  case 1 :: tail => println("list starting with 1 with an arbitrary tail")
  case Nil => println("Empty list")
  case Person("Joe", lastName) => println(s"Hello Joe $lastName")
}
```

You can use [typed actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/typed-actors.html) with Java instead if that helps, given that probably object-oriented decomposition is better than instanceof in Java's case since pattern-matching is not available.

Typed actors allow you to do method calls instead of message passing. Typed actors support asynchronous "fire-and-forget" methods, asynchronous future-returning methods, as well as blocking methods. Typed actors are to be used sparingly since they aren't really part of an actor model of computation, they are Akka's way of supporting object-oriented way of thinking in a message-passing framework, and the actor model and OO "RPC" are NOT the same. [Here](http://letitcrash.com/post/19074284309/when-to-use-typedactors) is a good post that covers some of that. As Akka's own documentation says:

> TypedActors can very easily be abused as RPC, and that is an abstraction which is well-known to be leaky. Hence TypedActors are not what we think of first when we talk about making highly scalable concurrent software easier to write correctly. They have their niche, use them sparingly.

Comment: That what I mean yes. I wonder why do people usually prefer to use untyped actor over typed ones? Typed ones seems make code more readable - less 'instanceof' / 'case' - involved. More object-oriented like. More typed like Java & scala languages are. Even if use pattern matching that does not look so clear as list of methods. As I said - easier to navigate in IDE.

Comment: Like I said, Scala DOES NOT require typed actors for anything to be wildly more productive than the OO approach - you need to learn about pattern matching to understand this. Scala is an FP-OOP hybrid and oftentimes OOP is at the wrong level of abstraction for a particular use case. Scala is type-safe and as a result, so is pattern-matching. There are many problems that object-oriented decomposition can't resolve without tons of boilerplate when pattern matching can. Feel free to look at Coursera's "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" by Martin Odersky, week 4, videos 4.5 and 4.6.

Comment: Also, have a look at "Functional Programming for Java Developers" by Dean Wampler (O'Reilly) - it discusses issues such as the above. It was written before Java 8 but it explains the philosophy of FP to Java developers, in a way that the new Java 8 books don't. The new books talk about how to use the new APIs, but not why a given approach would be better from a design perspective. Dean Wampler's book is only about 70 pages and is well worth the time. Martin Odersky's videos mentioned above are worth your time if you're trying to understand why untyped actors are better than typed ones.

Comment: As I mentioned, given Java's shortcomings in the pattern-matching department, typed actors MAY be preferred in some cases in Java. In Scala, I never had a single use case for them.

Comment: I know pattern matching and got some experience in scala. So no question about that. Hybrid - FP & OP but not typed and not-typed. UntypedActors just reminds me dynamic languages approach. Just feeling that is a little bit too dynamic with Actors.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I very much dislike dynamic languages so I understand the feeling. I think the main point is that since actors are extremely lightweight, it's easy to create many small actors that serve a small set of functions, therefore it's easy to look them up in the IDE. I think that there are many cases in which the IDE may be unable to help, e.g. when we use lambdas instead of defining concrete references to a function object on Scala.

Comment: Actually, in this case, perhaps a better book recommendation (also very short, but dense) is "Effective Akka" by Jamie Allen (also O'Reilly). It shows some design patterns that may be helpful when one is trying to wrap one's head around how to design real-world systems using this approach. But again, in Java, it may be preferable to use typed actors if one can resist the RPC temptation.

Comment: Also, there are many things in Scala that feel "dynamic" yet are type-safe, for example implicit conversions. I think the issue is to use one's judgment and preferences - type safety is ensured, the issue is though how one prefers to code, and that's an individual thing.

Comment: Speaking of preferences, there are for instance people in the Scala community who mix FP and OOP, mutability and immutability, based on need (e.g. mutability for iterative machine learning algorithms to make them run faster). Then there are people who think along the lines of "A monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors." I think the use case and one's preferences determine how one writes code. Probably a good guideline is, is it provably correct by inspection, is it scalable as designed without major refactoring, and do I enjoy coding this way. Otherwise it's one's own preference.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that typed actors don't allow you to switch behaviors, FSM-style (Akka has an FSM API). To my knowledge, you can't apply become/unbecome to typed actors, but you can to untyped actors. This may or may not be relevant, depending on the use case.

Comment: It's hardly a main reason why they didn't gained as much love as ordinary way

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reasonable pattern, you can use like this to take the advantage of lambda expression supported in Java 8 and above

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.japi.pf.ReceiveBuilder;

public class Root extends AbstractActor {
    public Root() {
       receive(ReceiveBuilder
            .match(DoThis.class, this::doThis)
            .match(DoThat.class, this::doThat).build());
    }

    private doThis(DoThis doThis) {}
    private doThat(DoThat doThat) {}
}
```